# php, echo <<< _END not fuctioninng

Tags: php

I'm new to php, and I have a problem with my code , with the echo <<< _END statement,
Here is my code,

```
 echo <<< _END
               // few code lines goes here

  _END;
```

Here is the error message,

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file,
expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or heredoc end (T_END_HEREDOC) or
${ (T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES) or {$ (T_CURLY_OPEN) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php
```

Comment: Show us the full code, probably your missing to close any loop.

Comment: The `_END;` must be the **first and only** thing on that line. There must be **no whitespace** before or after it!

Comment: Remove the white spaces for _END

Answer (score 11):

Whitespace is a problem.

```
echo <<<_END
        ^ no whitespace here!
v and none here either
_END;
```

Otherwise, the whole rest of the file is your HEREDOC, and the end of the file is unexpected.

Comment: The whitespaces before the first `_END` are not significants.